# subir archivos ajax laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax

Buen día
estoy trabajando con laravel 6 y trato de subir un archivo excel via ajax por medio de un modal
este es mi modal

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="excelForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel">Escoja su archivo</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form id="formImport" action="{{route('user.import')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <i class="fas fa-file-import fa-2x"></i> <input type="file" name="excel" id="excel" >
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">volver</button>
                    <button  class="btn btn-success" id="confirmExcel">Confirmar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

cuando hago la petición via ajax tengo el siguiente codigo

```js
 $('#formImport').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr('action');
       $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",form}
            
       }) .done(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
       
       
   })
```

tengo dos problemas, la petición demora bastante y el otro es cuando el controlador me retorna la respuesta en json no me sale en la consola, por el contrario me redirige a la url del controlador y alli si aparece el json con el mensaje de confirmación
si coloco el e.preventDefault() me sale este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
agradezco su ayuda

Comment: si lo coloco asi sale esto :: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation